# Changing the master volume in C#

Tags: c#, audio

Ok, I have a problem, I have tried so hard just to change the master volume in C#, it seems like the answerers of the questions appear to be doing rocket science, or they just add a bunch of extra junk.

Could someone just show me how I can make a class that has a Volume{get{}set{}} property in it that lets me change the master volume.  A requirement is that it has to work in 64 and 32 bit OS.  Nothing else, just a volume integer.

Comment: Hi, have you already followed this tutorial? http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/45693-controlling-sound-volume-in-c%23/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get an idea from the following code, just instead of putting those functions in events, invoke them in the property setter.

Do this :

```
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE = 0x80000;
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP = 0xA0000;
private const int APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN = 0x90000;
private const int WM_APPCOMMAND = 0x319;
private const int APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE = 0xE0000;


[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr SendMessageW(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg,
    IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void btnPlayPause_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE);
}

private void btnMute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_MUTE);
}

private void btnDecVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_DOWN);
}

private void btnIncVol_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendMessageW(this.Handle, WM_APPCOMMAND, this.Handle,
        (IntPtr)APPCOMMAND_VOLUME_UP);
}
```

hope this help.

Comment: Actually you basically did the same thing others do with the form and all, but thanks because this looks like it's actually failproof and it's pretty easy to understand.

Comment: This doesn't run through Windows Explorer, does it?  Because that very suspiciously won't work with what I am doing.

Comment: Oh, and by the way it doesn't work.  The software I am designing is supposed to replace Windows Explorer, so this doesn't work because it's messaging Explorer.